# Two ScheduledExecutorService overriding eachother?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, executor, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm trying to make two blinking circles that blink at different rates. I'm using ScheduledExecutorService in the Circle class to regulate the blinking, and its duration is set by the ms (milliseconds) variable in each Circle.

When I make one car individually, they blink at the correct rates (I have the black one set to 1000ms, the red set to 10ms). However, when I create them both and add them to my JLayeredPane, they both blink at the shorter period.

I'm not too familiar with the use of ScheduledExecutorService, so if someone could help me out with what's going wrong it'd be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class blinker extends JFrame
{
    JLayeredPane lp = new JLayeredPane();
    public carlight()
    {
        lp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        lp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 450));

        car c1 = new car(new Color(0, 0, 0), "1", 10, 0, 0);
        c1.setOpaque(false);
        car c2 = new car(new Color(255, 0, 0), "2", 1000, 100, 100);
        c2.setOpaque(false);
        c1.setBounds(0, 0, 450, 450);
        c2.setBounds(0, 0, 450, 450);

        lp.add(c2);
        lp.add(c1);

        add(lp);

        setTitle("Carlights");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        carlight cl = new carlight();
    }
}

class Circle extends JPanel
{
    private Color color;
    private String name;
    private long ms;
    private int x, y;
    private boolean on = true;
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        if(on)
        {
            g.setColor(color);
            int r = 50;
            g.fillOval(x, y, r, r);
            on = false;
        }
        else
        {
            on = true;
        }
    }

    public car(Color c, String s, long l, int x, int y)
    {
        color = c;
        name = s;
        ms = l;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        this.service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                repaint();
            }
        }, 0, ms, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have program logic in the paintComponent method, where you change the state of the boolean variable. You don't have full control over when or even if this method will be called, and in fact **both** paintComponents will be called when repaint is called which is why your blinkers aren't working. The solution: get the logic out of the paintComponent method by changing the state of the boolean field, on, elsewhere. Also you'll want to use a Swing Timer for better Swing threading.

You also will want to fix your use of layouts including avoiding use of setBounds. This is especially dangerous and unpredictable in your setup, using it with a BorderLayout. Myself, I'd not make the Circle class extend a JPanel but rather make it a logical class, not a component class, and then I'd have the drawing component, a class that does extend JPanel, hold instances of Circle classes and then draws them in its paintComponent.  For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BlinkerEg extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 450;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private List<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<>();

   public BlinkerEg() {
      circles.add(new Circle(Color.red, 1000, 0, 0, 450, this));
      circles.add(new Circle(Color.black, 60, 0, 0, 450, this));
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      for (Circle circle : circles) {
         circle.paint(g2);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      BlinkerEg mainPanel = new BlinkerEg();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("BlinkerEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class Circle {
   private Color color;
   private int x, y;
   private int diam;
   private JComponent component;
   private boolean on = true;

   public Circle(Color color, int ms, int x, int y, int diam, JComponent component) {
      this.color = color;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.diam = diam;
      this.component = component;

      new Timer(ms, new TimerListener()).start();
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      if (on) {
         g.setColor(color);
         g.fillOval(x, y, diam, diam);
      }
   }

   public boolean isOn() {
      return on;
   }

   public void setOn(boolean on) {
      this.on = on;
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         setOn(!isOn());
         component.repaint();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! (: By any chance would you know how to make them move position after blinking too? I tried changing x and y before painting in the paint method, but it seemed to move at a completely different rate than the blinking. Either way thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: @user3622688: again, don't change object state in paint or paintComponent. These methods are for painting and painting only. You would change position in the Timer's ActionListener, just like you change the state of the blink boolean.